# How to solve autowire problem in symfony 5.3.10?

Tags: php, html, symfony

As you can see in the code below, when I am trying to delete my category. It's give me following errors:

**Cannot autowire argument $category of "App\Controller\AdminController::deleteCategory()": it references class "App\Entity\Category" but no such service exists.**

This is the code of function I have created in AdminController.php:

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Utils\CategoryTreeAdminList;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

use App\Entity\Category;

#[Route('/admin')]

class AdminController extends AbstractController
{

```
#[Route('/delete-category/{id}', name: 'delete_category')]

public function deleteCategory(Category $category): Response
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->remove($category);
    $entityManager->flush();
    return $this->redirectToRoute('categories');
}
```

}

Following is the code where I have mentioned categoryList:

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Utils;

use App\Utils\AbstractClasses\CategoryTreeAbstract;

class CategoryTreeAdminList extends CategoryTreeAbstract
{

```
public $html_1 = '<ul class="fa-ul text-left">';
public $html_2 = '<li><i class="fa-li fa fa-arrow-right"></i>  ';
public $html_3 = '<a href="';
public $html_4 = '">';
public $html_5 = '</a> <a onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\');" href="';
public $html_6 = '">';
public $html_7 = '</a>';
public $html_8 = '</li>';
public $html_9 = '</ul>';


public function getCategoryList(array $categories_array)
{
    $this->categorylist .= $this->html_1;
    foreach ($categories_array as $value) {
        $url_edit = $this->urlgenerator->generate('edit_category', ['id' => $value['id']]);

        $url_delete = $this->urlgenerator->generate('delete_category', ['id' => $value['id']]);
        $this->categorylist .= $this->html_2 . $value['name'] . 
        $this->html_3 . $url_edit . $this->html_4 . ' Edit' . 
        $this->html_5 . $url_delete . $this->html_6 . 'Delete' . 
        $this->html_7;

        if (!empty($value['children'])) {
            $this->getCategoryList($value['children']);
        }

        $this->categorylist .= $this->html_8;
    }

    $this->categorylist .= $this->html_9;

    return $this->categorylist;
}
```

}

Comment: Check the entity `Category`, its path, its name space

Comment: Why are you building html outside of a view?

Comment: Did you add the Symfony SensioFrameworkExtraBundle to your project? I believe that's what's needed to convert the `{id}` in your route to the `Category` object. https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/index.html

Comment: this error is not related to any of the bundle or building html, this comes under the passing the classes as argument or injecting the entities as argument, i don't know why but its can solved as;

-passing the $id as argument
- writing this code, "$categories = $entityManager->getRepository(Category::class)->find($id);" after this code $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

it's may solve your problem, get a look with my answer....

Comment: @Ayush That (converting the id into an object) is exactly what the SensioFrameWorkExtraBundle does. This bundle is very commonly used and uses the exact syntax as posted in the question above (id in the route, object as a parameter in the method). So while your fix works, I still think it could have been more easily solved by installing the bundle (and no other edits are required!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@saddam Go ahead with this code..... you'll may solve your error with this and let me know if its solved.

```
#[Route('/delete-category/{id}', name: 'delete_category')]

public function deleteCategory($id): Response

{
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$category = $entityManager->getRepository(Category::class)->find($id);
$entityManager->remove($category);
$entityManager->flush();
return $this->redirectToRoute('categories');

}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Just to reiterate from the comments, yes the above code works but it should not be needed.  The [param converter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#automatically-fetching-objects-paramconverter) capability takes care of simple object fetches.  Plus, the getDoctrine method is deprecated in 5.4 and should not longer be used.

Comment: Actually my preferred method is working in my latest version too so i didn't care about this but you goes right and your changes also works good. thanks. @Cerad

Comment: @Cerad thanks for your concern your suggestion is quite helpful for my problem,,

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run this command: `composer require sensio/framework-extra-bundle`

Answer (score 0):

If you use symfony >= 5.4 you should not install `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` because `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` has been abandoned. See the solution above by Ayush